# Redirect everything to a single page with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm a total noob in HTAccess so please keep it simple.

On my website i don't use the www.-domain. Everything is on a subdomain.
However, when I refer to my website I refer to the www-section which redirect to the subdomain. This is simply done with PHP header() function.

What I want to do is redirect everything on www.jeroened.be to the subdomain. But, I also want to redirect http://www.jeroened.be/blog to http://subdomain.jeroened.be/blog.

The simpliest thing for me would be that everything is redirected to the index.php where I do my redirect to the subdomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you're asking for. It redirects everything to the index page.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule . index.php
```

You may hit an issue with it though in that it will also redirect images, css, etc... to the index page!

The following folder structure / .htaccess may be more appropriate.

- "App/Public" Public (All files that are publicly accessibly go in
  here - index.php, css, etc...)
- "App/Php" (Php files for your application)

---

```
RewriteEngine On

# If the requested file doesn't exist, redirect request to index.php  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know it was that easy.